# ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse with Traefik

Tags: docker, traefik, swarm

I would like to change an apache/tomcat ProxyPass configuration to a traefik/tomcat configuration in Docker Swarm. I've try some explained here https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#frontends, but it doesn't work:

Apache config:

```
ProxyPass       /sso ajp://server_host:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse    /sso ajp://server_host:8080/app
```

Docker Swarm config:

```
Traefik config in my docker-compose file:
traefik.frontend.rule=Host:external_dns;PathPrefix:/sso;ReplacePath:/app
```

And tomcat in docker image with a war application (context "app")

But it doesn't work, `/sso` is redirected (302) to `/app`

Who can i do a redirect from fontend to backend ?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved after editing the param `ReplacePathRegex`:

```
traefik.frontend.rule=Host:external_dns;PathPrefix:/sso;ReplacePathRegex:^/sso/(.*) /app/$$1
```